# How I can set a keyboard shortcut to access the Applications or Places menu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-panel, gnome-classic, appmenu

How I can set a keyboard shortcut to access the Applications or Places menu in gnome classic on ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: I don't even find where I can set any keyboard shortcuts... Seem the preferences menu is much 'lighter' than in 12.04 with Unity?!

Comment: Actually I don't use Unity. For setting any keyboard shortcut you may want to visit keyboard section in system settings. But I didn't find any option to set a shortcut for applications menu.

Comment: I don't use Unity, but Gnome Classic. I installed Unity 12.04 and then instaklled 'gnome-panel'. Now I have what I think is Gnome Classic, but without a keyboard entry in the settings menu. I seem to be missing a package. But probably this is a different question I should post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Applications > System Tools > System Settings > Keyboard. Open the "Shortcuts" tab.

There it be. :) The default for the Applications menu is Alt+F1.

[image: keyboard shortcuts screen]

Comment: Alt+F1 is hotkey for Activities overview, but NOT for applications menu !

Comment: It launches my application Dashboard. (?)

Comment: That is the dash, not the app menu some people are referring to (the menu that replaces the dash in Gnome Classic)