# Key for expanding Application menu in Gnome-Classic for 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, gnome-classic, metacity

1. In Gnome-Classic (metacity) in 14.04,

   - is there a key to invoke the Applications menu?
   - is there a key to switch between the items on the top panel, such as the Applications menu, Places, wireless icon, battery, time,
     shutdown/suspend/logout/lock menu, ...?
2. If possible, How shall I add the key for Application menu?

   To add a key for bringing out application menu, what is the command for doing that?
3. Unlike https://askubuntu.com/a/133915/1471, there is no key for  the
   Applications menu in my case.

   My 14.04 comes with compiz+unity, and then I install
   metacity+gnomeclassic.  Do they share the same keyboard settings? Is
   that the reason why I don't have key for the Application menu?

   [image]

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `ALT`+`F1`?

Comment: Did you see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/132871/how-i-can-set-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-access-the-applications-or-places-menu ?

Comment: @Helio: Thanks, unlike the link, there is no key for  the Applications menu in my case. My 14.04 comes with compiz+unity, but then I install metacity+gnomeclassic.  Do they share the same keyboard settings?

Comment: I don't know. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

With a dirty workaround, it can be done quite well. Using `xdotool`, you can make it move the mouse to the position of the Applications menu, open it and automatically move back to its original position.

Since all happens very quickly *and* the mouse is moved back to its original position, you won't notice it.

[image]

The script assumes your Applications menu is in the upper left corner, like in the image above. If that is not the case, the coordinates in `cmd1` have to be altered.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

cursordata = subprocess.check_output(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).decode("utf-8").split()
loc = [d.split(":")[1] for d in cursordata[:2]]
cmd1 = "xdotool mousemove 10 5"; cmd2 = "xdotool click 1"; cmd3 = "xdotool mousemove "+(" ").join(loc)
for cmd in [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]:
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

In detail:

fetch the current mouse position:

```
cursordata = subprocess.check_output(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).decode("utf-8").split()
```

Parse the output (x/y) into coordinates:

```
loc = [d.split(":")[1] for d in cursordata[:2]]
```

Run the commands `[cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]` to subsequently:

- move the mouse to the Applications menu
- click
- move the mouse back to wherever it was

```py
for cmd in [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]:
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

#### How to use the script

1. Install `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Paste the script into an empty file, save it as `open_appmenu.py`
3. Test-run it with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/open_appmenu.py
   ```
4. If all works well, add it to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/open_appmenu.py
   ```

#### Move to the other items

Once you opened the Applications menu, you can simply switch to the next item with the arrow keys.

---

### *Edit: generalized version*

Below a version of the script that can be used in a flexible way, to click on the screen on *any* position, to be changed easily. The script can be run with two options:

1. to *set* (remember) the current mouse location:

   ```
   run_click -set
   ```
2. to click on the last-remembered position:

   ```
   run_click -run
   ```

If no position was set, a zenity message appears, inviting to set a position:

[image]

The script creates a hidden file; `~/.run_click` where it stores the latest remembered coordinates.

As a test, I put both commands under the key combinations: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, making it easy to change the click position on the spot.

#### How to set up

1. like in the first script, Install `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `run_click` (no extension) in `~/bin` (create the directory if necessary) and *make the script executable*.
3. If you just created `~/bin`, run `source ~/.profile`.
4. Test both commands, first `run_click -set`, then `run_click -run` to see if all works as expected.
5. Add both commands to two different key combinations: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the commands.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys
import os

option = sys.argv[1]
datafile = os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], ".run_click")

def get_mousepos():
    cursordata = subprocess.check_output(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).decode("utf-8").split()
    return [d.split(":")[1] for d in cursordata[:2]]

if option == "-run":
    try:
        data = open(datafile).read()
        coords = (" ").join([l for l in data.splitlines()])
    except FileNotFoundError:
        message = "Please run the command: 'run_click -set' first, to set the click position"
        subprocess.Popen(["zenity", "--info", "--text", message])
    else:
        cmd1 = "xdotool mousemove "+coords; cmd2 = "xdotool click 1"; cmd3 = "xdotool mousemove "+(" ").join(get_mousepos())
        for cmd in [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]:
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
            time.sleep(0.05)
elif option == "-set":
    open(datafile, "wt").write(("\n").join(get_mousepos()))
```

Comment: Thanks. I happened to find that by default, super+s  can expands Applications menu. This isn't listed in System settings -> Keyboard -> shortcuts, so I am not sure why the shortcut works. In Unity, the same shortcut is used for switching workspaces.