# How can I open a menu with a shortcut key if no shortcut key exists for the menu?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, rhythmbox, banshee, indicator-sound

Is there a keyboard shortcut to open/drop-down the sound menu/indicator, in order e.g. to see the currently playing song? If not, how could I set one?

Comment: What program do you use?

Comment: I took the liberty to change the title, to make it a generalized version of this question:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/605234/key-for-expanding-application-menu-in-gnome-classic-for-14-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the script below under a shortcut key, you can make *any* menu item drop down, if no shortcut exists for it, including the sound menu:

[image]

It actually is pretty much the same answer as posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605234/key-for-expanding-application-menu-in-gnome-classic-for-14-04), but the question is different. I took the liberty however to broaden (the title of) your question a bit to cover possible future similar questions.

#### What it does

The script simulates a mouse move to the menu or icon, clicks and then returns the mouse to where it was. This all happens in a split second, so you won't notice it at all.

It can be used in a flexible way, to click on the screen on *any* position, to be changed easily. It runs with two options:

1. to *set* (remember) the current mouse location:

   ```
   run_click -set
   ```
2. to click on the last-remembered position:

   ```
   run_click -run
   ```

If no position was set, a zenity message appears, inviting to set a position

The script creates a hidden file; `~/.run_click` where it stores the latest remembered coordinates.

#### How to use

1. Install `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `open_menu` (no extension) in `~/bin`. Create the directory if necessary, and *make the script executable*.
3. If you just created `~/bin`, run `source ~/.profile`.
4. Test both commands, first `open_menu -set`, then `open_menu -run` to see if all works as expected.
5. Now create *two* shortcuts: one to make the script remember the position of your menu item, the second one to actually open the menu. choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the commands to two different shortcut key combinations:

   ```
   open_menu -set
   ```

   and

   ```
   open_menu -run
   ```

Now place the mouse on the sound menu icon and press the first shortcut key. From then on, you can open the menu with the second shortcut key.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import sys
import os

option = sys.argv[1]
datafile = os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], ".run_click")

def get_mousepos():
    cursordata = subprocess.check_output(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).decode("utf-8").split()
    return [d.split(":")[1] for d in cursordata[:2]]

if option == "-run":
    try:
        data = open(datafile).read()
        coords = (" ").join([l for l in data.splitlines()])
    except FileNotFoundError:
        message = "Please run the command: 'run_click -set' first, to set the click position"
        subprocess.Popen(["zenity", "--info", "--text", message])
    else:
        cmd1 = "xdotool mousemove "+coords; cmd2 = "xdotool click 1"; cmd3 = "xdotool mousemove "+(" ").join(get_mousepos())
        for cmd in [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]:
            subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
            time.sleep(0.05)
elif option == "-set":
    open(datafile, "wt").write(("\n").join(get_mousepos()))
```

Comment: Generally it works if I run the scripts explicitly.
But, I do the steps you suggest and when I try to execute one of these commands I receive a "command not found" error.
I tried assigning the full path as a command and it also doesn't work...

Comment: @MakisH What do you mean by *explicitely*? It should always work! If not let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentaly pressed enter while commenting. I editted my comment.

Comment: @MakisH where do you store the script? under which name? Did you make it executable? Also important: did you either run `source ~/.profile` or log out/in? It is needed if you just created the directory `~/bin` to make it show up in `$PATH`.

Comment: I store it under my home, at bin/, with name open_menu. I made it executable by the properties menu. I just created the directory, so I added it as you said, by running this command (while I was in the ~/bin/ directory).

Comment: I also tried to logout/login and still, "command not found"

Comment: @MakisH if you run `echo $PATH`, is `/home/<yourname>/bin` listed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24301/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-makish).

Comment: So, I was able to run it with your suggestion in chat: "python3 /absolute/path/to/open_menu -run" Thanks for the answer! :-)

Comment: @MakisH Perfect! It is weird though, in Ubuntu, `~/bin` is included in `$PATH` by default. However, let's celebrate it works :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not a specific shorcut to open the Sound Indicator, but you can press Alt+F10 to focus the Menu Indicator and translate to the Sound Indicator.

Comment: I already had found this but, unfortunately, it doesn't work if I have e.g. a firefox window active. Thank's for the answer though! :)